# how to use CSOM in UWP in Visual Studio to grab a list or site's full user permissions

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, csom, visual-studio, .net

I've tried searching for tutorials or guides but could anyone point me in the direction of using a .NET application that grabs a sharepoint online site/lists users and their permission levels?

Thank you.